# Some strange errors when moving from MikTex on windows to Ubuntu TeX.

Tags: compiling, windows, miktex, ubuntu

I have some tex code that I used to compile successfully (actually, with some 3 non-important warnings) on Windows using MikTex. When I try to compile it on Ubuntu using:

```
tex composition-body.tex
```

I get the following errors:

```
rafid@MyLaptop:~/Desktop/Composition$ tex composition-body.tex 
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
(./composition-body.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \title
          {SOME TITLE}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \author
            {SOME AUTHOR}

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.40 \begin
           {document}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.42 \maketitle

?
```

Any idea why is that happening? By the way, I had to press "Enter" after every error for the compile to proceed!

Just in case you need this, I am using the EuroGraphics template:
http://www.eg.org/EG/Publications/guidelines

UPDATE: I tried what was proposed by Lian, and now I am getting these errors:

```
rafid@MyLaptop:~/Desktop/Composition$ pdflatex composition-body.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./composition-body.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.
(./composition-body.aux)

! LaTeX Error: The font size command \normalsize is not defined:
           there is probably something wrong with the class file.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.40 \begin{document}

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.42 \maketitle

? 

! LaTeX Error: Environment abstract undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.44 \begin{abstract}

? 

! LaTeX Error: Environment classification undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.59 \begin{classification}
                        % according to http://www.acm.org/class/1998/
?
```

Comment: post the entire preamble section of your tex file. From the output, it doesn't look like your file has specified a documentclass.

Comment: It sounds like you have a latex file (the commands like maketitle, and environments like abstract), but it does not have a `\documentclass` specified on the top. Is it a part of a larger project?  Do you also have a file like `composition-header.tex` or something like that?  How do you usually compile the file in miktex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem that you're running LaTeX on a document which should be included. Run LaTeX on the main document instead.

On MiKTeX perhaps your editor used the main document automatically (project setting).

When I read the file name `composition-body.tex` it reads like a part but not the main document. Typeset the main or frame document which uses `\include` or `\input` to read in `composition-body.tex`.

I had a look at the your linked template. There's a file `EGauthorGuidelines-body.inc` which contains title, author, abstract, `\begin{classification}...` just like your body file. But this file is not compilable, even if you rename it to get the extension `.tex`. Instead, `EGauthorGuidelines-cgf-fin.tex` has to be compiled. This file uses `\input{EGauthorGuidelines-body.inc}` to include the body file.

Comment: Ops, you are right, how did I make this mistake? No, on Windows I am using MeWa editor which asks me about the main file. So I already know this, but it was a mistake. But I think Lian's answer below (using latex rather than tex) is correct also, because I must have tried it before on the main file (composition.txt rather than composition-body.txt) before, yet got some error. I still get some error, so I will re-edit the post and add the errors. It will be great if you can help me with them.

Comment: @Rafid: since the warnings are a different subject, please open a separate question for that. This keeps the site readable and sorted (for each subject a question with appropriate tags, to be found by others who look for an existing solution).

Answer (score 1):

Try running

`latex composition-body.tex` or `pdflatex composition-body.tex`

instead of plain `tex`, which won't recognise LaTeX commands such as `\title` etc.

Comment: I tried it. It seems better, but still got many errors. I updated my question for the new errors.